# Partial inversion of an admittance matrix

Tags: matrices, inverse, numerical-linear-algebra, symmetric-matrices

In power system short-circuit calculations we build a matrix based on the system admittances, $Y_p$. The off-diagonals are always equal to each other, so when we build the $Y_p$ matrix we only need to calculate those I've colored red, e.g. $Y_{p_{4,3}}=Y_{p_{3,4}}$.

We invert $Y_p$ to find $Z_p$ which we can use directly for the short-circuit calculations.

For larger systems this matrix can be huge as it has dimensions based on the number of buses. In my example below the $Y_p$ is for a 5 bus system:

[image]

If I want to find the bus voltage at bus 3 during a fault at bus 4, all I need for the calculations are the elements $Z_{p_{4,3}}$ and $Z_{p_{4,4}}$ from the $Z_p$ matrix (highlighted in green below).

[image]

Is there an approach to calculate just those elements (or a sub-matrix including them), without having to invert the **entire** $Y_p$ matrix?

---

**Motivation**

To show how the $Y$ matrix is constructed.  Below is an electrical circuit.  The $Y$ matrix is created from these values.  The on-diagonal elements are the sum of the admittances connected to a node.  The off-diagonal elements are the negative of admittances connected between nodes.

[image]

So, $Y_{p_{1,1}}=15$,$Y_{p_{2,2}}=8.83$, and $Y_{p_{3,3}}=4.33$.

$Y_{p_{1,2}}=-5$, $Y_{p_{1,3}}=0$, $Y_{p_{2,1}}=Y_{p_{1,2}}$, $Y_{p_{2,3}}=-3.33$.

So, the resulting $Y_p$ matrix for the above circuit will be,

$$Y_p=\begin{pmatrix}
15 & -5 & 0\\
-5 & 8.83 & -3.33\\
0 & -3.33 & 4.33 
\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: The problem is that gaussian elimination on the block matrix $[A \vert I]$ with $I$ the identity matrix is really fast so calculating the inverse is typically easier. Like you can calculate the determinant and use the formula for the adjugate to get those exact entries but by the time you've done that have you really saved time? Probably not.

Comment: Thanks, what about a 40,000 x 40,000 with complex entries?

Comment: Do you need it to be exact or will an numerical approximation do?

Comment: @CyclotomicField - an approximation would be fine if error on the order of < 1%.  Do you know an approach?

Comment: Do have any reason to believe $Y_P$ will have additional structure like being positive semi-definite, strictly diagonally dominant, symmetric, etc?

Comment: @CyclotomicField  I updated my question to show how the $Y$ matrix is constructed.  I don't know about the first 2 (semi-definite, strictly diagonally dominant) but it will be a symmetric matrix since the corresponding off-diagonals are equal (e.g. $Y_{{row,col}}$=$Y_{{col,row}}$ etc.)

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Yes, it will have complex entries when inductors/capacitors present.  The example i added to my question just uses resistors so all real.  It is not Hermitian as the corresponding diagonals are not conjugates but are equal (when using complex entries).  It is symmetric since it equals its transpose.

Comment: Can you write $Y$ as a product of matrices that encode information on the topology of the circuit and its impedances?  You may want to take a look at Professor Gilbert Strang's [lecture](https://youtu.be/6-wh6yvk6uc).

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo I will look into it.  Will that path lead me to finding elements of $Z_p$ without having to invert $Y_p$.

Comment: @relayman357 My point is that your matrix comes from a graph-theoretic context (rather than, say, `rand(n,n)` on Matlab) and neglecting its structure is unwise.  Exploiting its structure may allow you to speed up the inversion. If you have structure, don't neglect it.